# Laravel Fortify email verification redirects to /home

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel Fortify for the auth of my project. After a *user* has registered, it should be redirected to a page telling it that a mail have been sent - however, it redirects to `/`.

As per the docs I have done the following:

1. My `User` model implements `MustVerifyEmail`.
2. I've created the view I want to show (`views/auth/verify-email.blade.php`).
3. I've got the following lines in the `boot` method of `FortifyServiceProvider`:

```php
Fortify::verifyEmailView(function () {
    return view('auth.verify-email');
});
```

However, after the user registers it is redirected to `/` and not the view I specified!

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#registration) says:

> If the registration attempt is successful, Fortify will redirect the user to the URI configured via the `home` configuration option within your application's `fortify` configuration file. If the login request was an XHR request, a 200 HTTP response will be returned.

So, if you have not changed your `fortify.home` config, it will be defaulted to `/home` (as that is the default in the config file).

[Here is the source code](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/3ee9b62ce1dd0966d4ff7bff34c7c364a47dab6d/src/Http/Controllers/RegisteredUserController.php#L54-L58) so you can see what it will do ONCE the user is registered, and [this is the response](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/3ee9b62ce1dd0966d4ff7bff34c7c364a47dab6d/src/Http/Responses/RegisterResponse.php#L21) (last line of code).

`Fortify::verifyEmailView` corresponds to **showing a verification to the user that it must verify it email**, but as the documentation says:

> After registration, you may wish for users to verify their email address before they continue accessing your application.

So, this will **NOT** show the message IF the user is not logged in or was just registered **WITHOUT** being logged in.

How does this work ? This is done thanks to Laravel itself, it uses a `Middleware` to do this, and Fortify just uses these standards. [This is the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/EnsureEmailIsVerified.php) of the `EnsureEmailIsVerified` middleware.

If I am not confused, this is not `on` by default, so you have to tell which routes you would like this to be working on or turn it `on` as a `global` middleware. [This is the default config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Kernel.php#L64) for all middlewares in Laravel 8.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, the explanation is much appreciated! However, when I **either** add `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class` to the `$middleware` array in Kernel.php, registering redirects to /email/verify but with an error for too many redirects (assuming because the `verified` middlewear then applies to that page as well). If I put the middleware on `/home` in web.php, **everything** redirects to /email/verify and the page displays correctly. Any ideas?